# how to quit a loop or onClick(android)?

Tags: java, android

Got a problem here on exiting onclick.

The program uses shared preferences to get inputs,
and if `String name = "User"`, the program wouldn't let the user click this button and just display an alert dialog box.

This is my code below:

```
public void onClick(View v) {                   
    name = shared.getString("sharedname", "User");
    gender = shared.getInt("sharedgender", 0);
    age = shared.getInt("sharedage", 0);
    weight =shared.getInt("sharedweight", 0);
    height = shared.getInt("sharedheight", 0);
    if(name=="User")
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(cont)
        .setMessage("Please input your information first")
        .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
        break;//error
    }
//code code code, rest of the code to be cancelle
```

Comment: And why aren't you just using `return`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `equals(Object)` method  instead of `==` operator

```
if(name.equals("User"))
                {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(cont)
                    .setMessage("Please input your information first")
                    .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
                    return ;
                }
```

**The equals() method of java.lang.Object acts the same as the == operator; that is, it tests for object identity rather than object equality. The implicit contract of the equals() method, however, is that it tests for equality rather than identity. Thus most classes will override equals() with a version that does field by field comparisons before deciding whether to return true or false.**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `break`, simply use a `return;` statement.

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("User")){
// your code
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(ValueSelling.this);
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.termsTitle));
                    alertDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.terms));
alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
alertDialog.setButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }});

                    alertDialog.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {




                        }});
                    alertDialog.show();
```